# How to pass complex object on query to graphql

Tags: graphql

Just found graphql recently and i'm pretty amazed so far by everything it does, but i'm stucked in a question.

How to pass complex objects to queries? Take this query string as example:

filter={"id":"category","value":"123"}&filter={"id":"brand","value":"sony"}

There is the input type directive i could use to do the id and value, but what about the list? We can't use list, so, there is any other way to pass a complex object to query?

Answer (score 0):

The way we handle this by defining a new `input` type that is a complex object. For example:

```
extend type Query {
  myQuery(input: MyQueryInput!): MyQueryPayload
}

input MyQueryInput {
  item1: String!
  item2: Int!
}

query MyQuery(input: MyQueryInput) {
  myQuery {
    id
    value
  }
}
```